# Detect the position of a pattern of numbers in a matrix in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, detection

I am looking for a R function which detect the position of a pattern (vector of numbers) in a matrix or a data frame of numbers.

Thanks

Stéphane

example :

```
pattern <- c(2,2,2,2)
data<-t(data.frame(
    v1 = c(2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
    v2 = c(2,2,2,9,9,0,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
    v3 = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,9,1,1,0,0,0),
    v4 = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)))
```

Comment: voting to close as unclear: what are the correct answers for this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your new rules, may be this helps:

```
data1 <- data
#changing some elements to test the code
data1[2,8] <-2 
data1[4,1] <- 1

##The code is for the row

indx <- which(t(sapply(split(data1 == pattern, row(data1)), {
function(x) colSums(sapply(1:(length(x) - 3), function(i) x[seq(i, i + 3)]), 
    na.rm = TRUE) == 4
})), arr.ind = TRUE)
indx
# row col
# 3   3   1
#3   3   2
#4   4   2
#3   3   3
#4   4   3
#3   3   4
#3   3   5
#3   3   6
#3   3   7
#3   3   8
#3   3   9
#3   3  10
#3   3  11
```

A correction in previous code for colwise operation

```
 which(apply(pattern==data, 2, function(x){if(all(!is.na(x) & x)) x else rep(FALSE, 4)}),arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Changing the pattern to 1

```
 pattern <- rep(1,4)
  which(apply(pattern==data, 2, function(x){if(all(!is.na(x) & x)) x else rep(FALSE, 4)}),arr.ind=TRUE)
 #row col
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
which(apply(pattern == data, 2, all))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

should do the trick. We make use of the fact that matrices are store column-wise and that `pattern` will be reused.

Slightly more efficient is

```
which(colSums(pattern == data) == nrow(data))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the position of the pattern in the data frame (row and column)

Comment: Well, these gives you the columns which matches `pattern`. This is uniquely specified by the column (as the matrix has 4 rows). So i don't understand what you mean by the row position?

Comment: pattern is a row vector but I ignore how to create a row vector in R

Comment: data is an small example, my data frame is 557x54

Comment: @user3771210 Well, the `pattern` you have given here is just a vector (neither a row nor column vector). Anyway, the answer can easily be modified to work on your data. (Just transpose your `data.frame` and the output will be the *rows* where the matches are.)

Comment: it doesn't if I transpose my data frame. The real one is 557x54 and the code is "nrow(data)" which is nonsense (data is just a small example)